# Dynamic routing in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to create dynamic stubs as webservices. My idea is to load at every request a definition file and return data for corresponding URL. 
The definition file could look like this:

```
/api/users {users:["john", "jack", "jake"]}
/api/users/1 {user:"john"}
/api/some-data/1 {data:"some data"}
```

In an application I created on behalf of a tutorial I find:

```
router.post('/some-irl', function (req, res) {
    //some code
    return {some JSON}
});
```

But this definition looks static to me, which should be there before I start Node.js Is it possible to define /some-irl at the time then request occures?

**EDIT**

Actually, I was intending to do somehting like this: https://github.com/typicode/json-server but it is already there!

Comment: Take a look at [doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param) - I'm assuming you use ```express``` and route path can have mini regex-like matching where you can name parameter, make it optional or selective, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a `use` middleware, which can check the path and decide whether to handle it or pass it on:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // req.path
    // decide what to do
    // respond or next()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define variables in the routes, use `:` before the variable name to define it, and then you'll get the value in req.params:

```
route.get('/api/users/:user/', function (req, res) {
   var username = req.params.user;
});
```